# Dash player for segment list with non-zero repeat count

Tags: mpeg-dash

```
  <Period programDateTime='2021-03-17T07:15:26.239Z' duration='PT1M04.078S'>
    <AdaptationSet contentType='video' mimeType='video/mp4' par='16:9' id='7'>
      <SegmentList timescale='90000' presentationTimeOffset='4327131510'>
        <SegmentTimeline>
          <!-- Doesn't work -->
          <S t='4327131510' d='2903310' r='1' />

<!--      Uncomment below and remove the above and manifest will work -->   
<!--      <S t='4327131510' d='2903310'/>-->
<!--      <S t='4330034820' d='2903310'/>-->
        </SegmentTimeline>
      </SegmentList>

      <Representation id='1280x720' codecs='avc1.4d0029' width='1280' height='720' bandwidth='100000'>
        <BaseURL>http://localhost:8000/downloaded/</BaseURL>
        <SegmentList>
          <Initialization sourceURL='1.m4v' />
          <SegmentURL media='1.m4v' />
          <SegmentURL media='2.m4v' />
        </SegmentList>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
```

Dash player starts playing the manifest however, it skips the 2.m4v and reduces the size of video to just first segment. However, if I remove the repeat count field and specify each segment explicitly in segmentTimeline then it works fine.

This manifest also works fine in Shaka player.

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest doesn't look right. I don't think the first segment list with the time line should be there. I would try:

```
<Period programDateTime='2021-03-17T07:15:26.239Z' duration='PT1M04.078S'>

  <AdaptationSet contentType='video' mimeType='video/mp4' par='16:9' id='7'>
  
    <Representation id='1280x720' codecs='avc1.4d0029' width='1280' height='720' bandwidth='100000'>
    
      <BaseURL>http://localhost:8000/downloaded/</BaseURL>
      
      <SegmentList timescale='90000' duration='2903310'>
      
        <Initialization sourceURL='1.m4v' />
        <SegmentURL media='1.m4v' />
        <SegmentURL media='2.m4v' />
        
      </SegmentList>
      
    </Representation>
    
  </AdaptationSet>
  
</Period>
```